# $ionicposition only setting correct values on a modal the first time a modal is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ionic-framework

I have created a custom select directive and within this directive when you tap into the options it should use $ionicposition to locate the selected option based on the HTML element ID, and then scroll to it using $ionicscroll delegate.

This is the function which locates the option, and then scrolls to it:

```
  private scrollToOption(selectedCode: activeh.objects.ICode): void {
    this.$timeout(() => {
        let item: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("code-" + selectedCode.CodeID);
        if(item){
            var itemPosition = this.$ionicPosition.offset(angular.element(item));
            this.$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('modalContent').scrollTo(0, itemPosition.top + 40, false);
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

This is where the scrollTo function is called:

```
    private createModal(): void {
    this.$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/shared/directives/selectoption/selectoption.modal.html', {
        scope: this.$scope,
        hardwareBackButtonClose: false
    }).then((modal) => {
        this.selectModal = modal;
        this.selectModal.show();
        if (this.selectedVal !== undefined) {
            this.scrollToOption(this.selectedVal);
        }
    });
}
```

So like mentioned in the title, this code works perfectly but only the first time that the modal is opened. After the modal has been closed and opened again the $ionicposition.offset is returning values of only 0.

Comment: Do some research on caching in Ionic, it maybe that you need to disable caching. Looks like it's getting refreshed, need to stop that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (probably partial) solution to this, wherein instead of using .hide() to hide the modal I use .remove() to completely remove it forcing a complete rebuild.

This mimics the behaviour where it worked the first time as now every time the modal is opened is the 'first' time.